# Why when I use reflection on this JavaScript object I can't see a property defined in its prototype object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I am actually studying the **reflection** concept on a tutorial.

So I have the following code:

```
/* REFLECTION AND EXTEND:

REFLECTION: An object can look at itself listing and changing its properties and methods. So it means that a JavaScript object have the ability to look at its own properties and methods. We can use this feature of the JavaScript language to implement a very userful pattern called EXTEND.
*/


/* This is a generic person object that have 'firstname' and 'lastname' peropertiest setted on a 'Default' value. This generic person object provide also a getFullName() method that return the concatenation of the firstname and the lastname
*/
var person = {
    firstname: 'Default',
    lastname: 'Default',
    getFullName: function() {
        return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;  
    }
}

/* This john object represent a specific person but do not provide the getFullName() method: */
var john = {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe'
}

// don't do this EVER! for demo purposes only !!! 
/* This set the 'person' object on the proto variable of the john object. So from this john object I can also use the getFullName() method defined for the generic person object: */
john.__proto__ = person;


// Now, we are going to see an example of the use of reflection in JavaScript:


for (var prop in john) {            // Iterate on all the properties into the john object (prop is the current property during the iteration)
    if (john.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // propo is the current property name and john[prop] is the related value of this property into the john object:
        console.log(prop + ': ' + john[prop]);      
    }
}
```

The code is pretty neat and the comment explain what it does.

So I have a generic **person** object that provide the **getFullName()** method and I have also the **john** object that represent a specific person but that have not dfined the **getFullName()** method.

Then I do:

```
john.__proto__ = person;
```

that say that the **person** object is the prototype of the **john** object so it means that the **john** object inherite from the **person** object. So I will expect that now the **john** object have access alsto at the **getFullName()** method.

Then I use reflection to iterate on the **john** object and I print all the properties of this objects.

I obtain this result:

```
firstname: John
lastname: Doe
```

This seems to me pretty strange because, as I can see also in the tutorial, I would expect to see also this property:

```
getFullName: function() {
    return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;  
}
```

because now I have access to it.

Why I can't see it? What am I missing? What is the problem?

Comment: `if (john.hasOwnProperty(prop))` discards it, because it's not the object's own property.

Comment: It's just a brain fart. Not really worth an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one can see ***Juhana*** has already answered it in the comments but i would like to add my explanations.

When you do:

```
john.__proto__ = person;
```

I would say it connects two objects as `Object john` has prototype of `person`. So john has the access to all the properties available in the person object.

Still this does not adds the person object's properties to object john but they have a connection between them as per `__proto__`. So, john still has its own props as is and it can access the method in the person object.

This condition:

```
if (john.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
```

does not let it log properties of it's prototype.

*`hasOwnProperty`* limits the property access to the current object in the iteration.

Comment: Tnx, perfect explaination :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all avoid using **proto** as its not same in all browsers.
now  **proto** add things to prototype i.e making inheritance.
Upon using john.hasOwnProperty(prop) will be true only for the own properties and not for inherited properties,thats why getFullName